# Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> - React Router and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, router

I'm trying to create a protected route for authentication. I have a ProtectedRoute component as suggested in the docs, that looks like this:

```
interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  auth: AuthState;
}

const ProtectedRoute = ({
  children,
  auth,
  ...rest
}: RouteProps & ProtectedRouteProps): JSX.Element => {
    console.log(auth)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props: RouteProps) =>
        auth.isAuthenticated ? children : <Redirect to={{pathname: "/signin", state: "Please sign in" }} />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I then use it, and I want to show the state ("please sign in") if someone is redirected to the signin page.

I have a wrapper component that deals with routing:

```
export interface IWrapper {
    auth: AuthState
}

class Wrapper extends Component<IWrapper> {
    constructor(props: IWrapper){
        super(props);
        console.log(props)
    }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <HeaderContainer />
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/signup">
            <SignUpView />
          </Route>
          <ProtectedRoute auth={this.props.auth} path="/dashboard">
              <DashboardContainer />
          </ProtectedRoute>
          </Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/signout" component={SignUpView}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn}></Route>

        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
    auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Wrapper)
```

Here's my signin page:

```
export default class SignIn<RouteComponentProps> extends Component {
    constructor(props: RouteComponentProps){
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.location.state ? (
                    <h2>You were redirected</h2>
                ) : ("")}
                <SignInForm />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The typescript compiler says that I can't do props.location because "Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'."

I really don't understand what this means. In the type definitions for RouteComponentProps you have:

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}, C extends StaticContext = StaticContext, S = H.LocationState> {
  history: H.History;
  location: H.Location<S>;
  match: match<Params>;
  staticContext?: C;
}
```

So what's the problem? I've tried using Redirect props, but that doesn't work either. I'm a n00b at Typescript so if anyone could help I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having read all of your code, my guess is that you can just change `SignIn` class definition from

```
export default class SignIn<RouteComponentProps> extends Component { ... }
```

to

```
export default class SignIn extends Component<RouteComponentProps> { ... }
```

, then you should be good to go.

In general *generic* type *parameters* are annotated following the name of the class, which in your case are not needed. In the `extends` clause *concrete* type *arguments* for the component to be extended are set. If you just write `extends Component` and don't specify the props type via `Component<RouteComponentProps>`, the default type `{}` of `Component` is used and TS cannot find `location` property on a common object literal `{}`.

More infos on generic classes can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes).

Comment: That did it! Fantastic, thnak you